# How to fix type error despite of casting it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i'm scraping some sites using selenium firefox-web-driver.first 7-8 links get **scraped** properly. after that , I'm getting TypeError.

In my code, Firefox web driver is being created and disposed(driver.quit() ) after parsing every link.

already tried casting it to stirng

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/umar/PycharmProjects/ShopToBDScraper/run_scraper.py", line 21, in <module>
   main()
 File "/home/umar/PycharmProjects/ShopToBDScraper/run_scraper.py", line 13, in main
   scrape_data(line,i)
 File "/home/umar/PycharmProjects/ShopToBDScraper/scraper/bs_scraper.py", line 381, in scrape_data
   cdn = str(math.ceil(float(cdn + 8) + ((float(cdn + 8) * 15) / 100)))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full error traceback, along with the snippet of code where your error is occurring

Comment: edited it. Is this alright ?

Comment: The problem would appear to be that the *original* value of `cdn` is a `str`, not an `int` to which you could add `8`. Trying to convert the final result of the calculation to a `str` is neither helpful nor necessary.

Comment: then why it isn't throwing errors for the first 6-7 links ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you error is from 8 being an int and not a string because cdn is a string. try:

```
cdn = str(math.ceil((float(cdn) + 8) + (((float(cdn) + 8) * 15) / 100)))
```

Comment: but it's running fine for the first 6-7 links .

Comment: If you're redefining cdn as str after those first 6-7 links are done, that will throw the error because you cannot concatenate an integer + str. Right now you have float(cdn + 8) which will concatenate the inside then change the answer to float. So if you're doing str + int, you're going to get the type error

Comment: cdn isnt being redefined. It’s using the same cdn for all links. However, i applied your solution and it’s working fine now. Thank you!should’ve noticed it myself.

Comment: you are redefining cdn because you're setting equal to a string in this line of code cdn = str(math.ceil(.....) after some iteration. When it's a string it can't concatenate with that integer. I couldn't tell you why it was working and all of a sudden stopped without seeing the full code, but glad that fixed the issue for you and happy scraping!